# Azure Standard Web Application Plan, several websites?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I decided to consolidate several of my blogs on azure, previously I only had 1 Orchard CMS blog hosted there. I upgraded my plan from free to Standard (this way I can point several domains there), but after I deployed my Ghost CMS blog to Azure it appears as a separate web app? How do I know that they are under the same Web App VM pricing plan?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current Portal: Navigate to your web app >> Scale >> APPS IN THIS APP SERVICE PLAN

Preview portal will give you more flexibility and information regarding hosting plan settings. Make sure to use it in case you need to move apps between them.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out, they were indeed in separate plans, so I moved them into 1 with the help of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23685094/is-it-possible-to-move-a-website-to-a-different-web-hosting-plan